# What is the condition for the critical point in a ternary system?

Tags: thermodynamics, stability

In the 2-component system, the condition for stability is
$$D = \frac{\partial ^2f}{\partial \phi ^2}>0$$
and the condition for the critical point is
$$\frac{\partial ^2f}{\partial \phi ^2}=0,\frac{\partial ^3f}{\partial \phi ^3}=0 $$

The condition for stability for a ternary system is given by
\begin{align}
    D = \frac{\partial ^2f}{\partial \phi _1 ^2}\frac{\partial ^2f}{\partial \phi _2 ^2} - \left(\frac{\partial ^2f}{\partial \phi _1 \phi _2}\right)^2 > 0
\end{align}

where $f$ is the free energy density and $\phi$ is the volume fraction.
My question is rather straightforward... What would be the condition for criticality be in a three component system? How do I go about proving this condition in the most generalized case?